# Get match value of another array

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables, combobox

I have an exported output list:

```
"Account Name","Caller Computer Name"
"Adminuser123","Server123"
"Guest","Server778"
"Mike","Server007"
```

- The list can randomly contain multiple same items in `"Account Name"` and also in `"Caller Computer Name"`

Also have a combobox filled with users (filling done by listing from somewhere else). 
Whenever select user from the combobox → check if the user exist in the output list → if yes write in textbox the servername of it, else write unknown.

What I did: (just the core part)

```
$combobox.add_SelectedIndexChanged($combobox_SelectedIndexChanged)
$combobox_SelectedIndexChanged = {
  If ($Row = $csv | Where-Object {$_.'Account Name' -eq $combobox.SelectedItem}) {
    $lockstatus.Text = "Locked on: $($Row.'Caller Computer Name')"
  } else {
    $lockstatus.Text = "Locked on: Unknown"
  }
}
```

Problem is every time I want to refer to that `$($Row.'Caller Computer Name')` I'm getting only the first indexed item and not the one I should according to the `$combobox.SelectedItem`.

How to refer to that value later in the code If I want to use that item later?
For example, if I select user Mike it will write `"Locked on: Server007"` and I want to refer later on the code to that that value (in our example server007) and insert that item/variable into some other string like:

```
$button.add_Click( 
{
Write-Host ($Row.'Caller Computer Name')
}
```

Once Clicked on the button expect to see wirte out:    `Server007`

Comment: You should use `ForEach` and `$_` and not `$Row`:  `... | ForEach {
    $lockstatus.Text = "Locked on: $($_.'Caller Computer Name')"...`

Comment: If I change the $($Row.'Caller Computer Name')" 
To   $($_.'Caller Computer Name')"
It's not showing any Locked on machine except the Unknown.

Comment: Also forget the `If` and place it in a `ForEach` loop: `$Row = $csv | Where-Object {$_.'Account Name' -eq $combobox.SelectedItem} | ForEach {...`

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I want to do.  the IF needed because IF the username in $combobox.selectedItem are not exist in the list ($_.'Account Name')  then I want to write Locked on: Unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$combobox.add_SelectedIndexChanged($combobox_SelectedIndexChanged)
$combobox_SelectedIndexChanged = {
  $Row = $csv | Where-Object {$_.'Account Name' -eq $combobox.SelectedItem}  
  If ($Row) {
    $lockstatus.Text = "Locked on: $($Row.'Caller Computer Name')"
  } else {
    $lockstatus.Text = "Locked on: Unknown"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I want to do. the IF needed because IF the username in $combobox.selectedItem are not exist in the list ($_.'Account Name') then I want to write Locked on: Unknown
Your option is not working as the script don't know what to do with the "esle"

Comment: Ok, you basically can't assign something in the `If ()` condition: I have changed my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You could read the `exported output list` into a hash array:

```
$HashAccounts = @{}
ForEach ($Row in (Import-Csv 'ExportedOutputList.csv')) {
    $HashAccounts.Add($Row.'Account Name',$Row.'Caller Computer Name')
}
```

And use the the Account Name as the Key to retrieve the associated value:

```
$combobox.add_SelectedIndexChanged($combobox_SelectedIndexChanged)
$combobox_SelectedIndexChanged = {
  If ($HashAccounts[$combobox.SelectedItem]) {
    $lockstatus.Text = "Locked on: $($HashAccounts[$combobox.SelectedItem])"
  } else {
    $lockstatus.Text = "Locked on: Unknown"
  }
}
```

Comment: This option not good as In the 'ExportedOutputList.csv' could have  multiple same 'Account Name' and 'Caller Computer Names 'and it will result  error: "Item has already been added.

Comment: Agreed, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45814640/edit) your question to insert this not obvious restriction.

Comment: Thanks. Question edited, however your answer was the closest to the solution as it works (if I ignore the error). Would like to see solution when it works without any conflict.